# How to connect to my configured personal meek bridge in Tor client?

Tags: configuration, meek

I have configured a meek client with the following Tor configuration:

```
BridgeRelay 1
ORPort 9001
ExtORPort auto
SocksPort 0
ServerTransportListenAddr meek 0.0.0.0:7002
ServerTransportPlugin meek exec /opt/meek/meek-server/meek-server --log /var/lib/tor/meek.log --cert /opt/meek/cert.pem --key /opt/meek/key.pem
ExitPolicy reject :

Log notice file /var/lib/tor/notice.log
Log info file /var/lib/tor/info.log
Log debug file /var/lib/tor/debug.log
```

The machine's IP is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, and the logs show:

```
│ 19:58:41 [NOTICE] Your Tor bridge's hashed identity key fingerprint is 'Unnamed E268394539AB8608965885574B8FC701809CA095'
│ 19:58:41 [NOTICE] Your Tor server's identity key fingerprint is 'Unnamed DBC3063C7253363D6BD6AD9F30C24CCDEE85CA10
```

How should I configure my client-side Tor configuration file? My current configuration is as follows:

```
UseBridges 1
Bridge meek 8.222.162.84:7002 url=8.222.162.84:7002/



NickName client
Address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

HashedControlPassword 16:D46B5CED4E032DF2600006FA84654B68516FF33AA59951DD252B4222D2
CookieAuthentication 1


SocksPort 9050
ControlPort 9051


Log notice file /var/lib/tor/notice.log
Log info file /var/lib/tor/info.log
Log debug file /var/lib/tor/debug.log
```

how to modify my torrc file, so my client could get the meek server? thanks